# Compiler flags for diagnosing slow compilation

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization, icc

I have some code which compiles in ~6 seconds under g++ 4.8.5, but takes an extremely long time to compile under icpc 17.0.1. Like 30 minutes, though I haven't measured exactly. I would like to know why icpc is taking so long, but I cannot find any flags or options which might reveal to me what stage of the compilation icpc is stalling at.

For g++ I discovered the nice option "-ftime-report", but I cannot find anything similar for the intel compilers. Is there anything? Or is there some other way to try and diagnose this problem?

EDIT: Well I found the problem via some a very simple search of the source files, commenting out everything and then adding it back until I found the slowdown, but it would still be nice to know if there are any flags or tools for intel compilers to help with this sort of thing.

For those who might be curious or seeing something similar, the issue for me had something to do with some BOOST variadic macros I was using, so I suppose it is the preprocessor that has got itself in a knot somehow. I have attached the culprit macro below. It is fairly ugly, but it was just for a bit of automated debugging output. The outer product it is doing is only something like 6x6 at the most so it really shouldn't be a serious burden (and g++ handled it no problem), but it seems to have somehow broken the intel preprocessor.

```
     #define GET_M2_MATRIX_EL(r, PRODUCT)                                    \
     {                                                                       \
        str label = BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, PRODUCT);                           \
        str block = BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, PRODUCT);                           \
        int i = BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(2, PRODUCT);                               \
        int j = BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(3, PRODUCT);                               \
        std::ostringstream echo1;                                            \
       try {                                                                 \
        std::ostringstream echo2;                                            \
        echo1 <<     "  spec.get(Par::mass2,"<<label<<","<<i<<","<<j<<") = "; \
        double value1 = spec.get(Par::mass2,label,i,j); \
        echo2 <<     "  SLHAea::to<double>( slhaea.at("<<block<<").at("<<i<<","<<j<<").at(2) ) = "; \
        double value2 = SLHAea::to<double>( slhaea.at(block).at(i,j).at(2) ); \
        cout << echo1.str() << value1 <<endl;                                \
        cout << echo2.str() << value2 <<endl;                                \
        cout << endl;                                                        \
       } catch (const std::exception& e)                                       \
       { add_error(report,e,label+": "+block); }                             \
    }

     #define GET_M2_MATRIX(NAME,BLOCK,__IND1,__IND2) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(GET_M2_MATRIX_EL, ((NAME))((BLOCK))(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ(__IND1))(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ(__IND2)))
```